# Injecting helper function to remote shell

Tags: bash, function, ssh, export

I have a host that stores logs and I would like to have a special shell function to use whenever I log in. Unfortunately, I don't own that host, so I can't store it there and add to path.

Let's say my function is

```
myfxn() { echo 'hi'; }
```

I would like to do something like

```
ssh -t my-host-address "bash ; myfxn { echo 'hi' }"
```

However, once I get into the host, myfxn never gets define. However, it'd be defined if I run

```
myfxn() { echo 'hi'; }
```

I wonder if there's anyway to make this work.